# ubuntuon Lenovo IdeaPad 3 14itl05 can't boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 22.04

I have dual boot of Windows 11 and Ubuntu, but my Ubuntu can't boot and it shows an error like this. I'm newbie in Linux.
I've tried updating the BIOS, but I still can't.

[image]

Ubuntu version 22.04
laptop Lenovo IdeaPad 3 14itl05

Comment: Usually ACPI errors are warnings and not an issue. Have you updated UEFI firmware and if NVMe its firmware? If still issues with 22.04, try 23.04, although better to use 22.04LTS as 5 year life over short term 23.04's 9 months. Some new hardware needs newer kernel & drivers. My Dell with 11th Gen Intel, just worked with 22.04. I did have to have Windows fast startup & bitlocker off & had updated UEFI.